# Js/Ajax function into a Js file doesn't work

Tags: joomla-3.x, javascript, ajax, form

I'm not a programmer (This is my hobby, but I like to learn new things). :)

I'm developing a JComponent on my side, and I need to integrate an Ajax Call in order to check something.

But I have this problem:

Here my code put in media/my_component/js

```
$(document).ready(function() {


$("#avanti").click(function(){


  var codice_fiscale = $("#codice_fiscale").val();


//chiamata ajax
  $.ajax({

   //imposto il tipo di invio dati (GET O POST)
    type: "POST",

    //Dove devo inviare i dati recuperati dal form?
    url: 'index.php?option=com_doclf_jsajax&view=taskajaxes&task=checkcodicefiscale',

    //Quali dati devo inviare?
    data: "codice_fiscale=" + codice_fiscale,
    dataType: "html",

    //Inizio visualizzazione errori
    success: function(msg)
    {
      $("#risultato").html(msg); // messaggio di avvenuta aggiunta valori al db (preso dal file risultato_aggiunta.php) potete impostare anche un alert("Aggiunto, grazie!");
    },
    error: function()
    {
      alert("Chiamata fallita, si prega di riprovare..."); //sempre meglio impostare una callback in caso di fallimento
    }
  });
});
  });
```

Unfortunately, if I call it from

```
$doc = Factory::getDocument();
$doc->addScript(Uri::base() . '/media/com_doclf_users/js/codice_fiscale.js');
```

I receive a error on debug

```
ncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
at codice_fiscale.js:1
```

Instead, if I put it into a default.php inside the script tag (like `<script> my script </script>`) it works.

Can anybody explain to me why?

Thanks in advance.

Andrea

Comment: Try replacing `$(document).ready(function() {` with `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {`

Comment: @Lodder Thanks! Works, perfectly! :) 
Another question: this is a correct way to do this or not? 
I'm trying to understand how is the best way to do things in joomla.

Comment: Glad it worked. I've added a proper answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd be best off using the `jQuery` global scope and passing `$` as an alias inside the function instead:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
```

This helps prevent any conflicts with other 3rd party libraries that also use the `$` namespace.

Comment: Works Perfectly! :)

Answer (score 0):

The `addScript` method will be adding the `<script>` tag for your JS before `jQuery`. You can solve this easily by adding `JHtml::_('jquery.framework');` before your `addScript`. Still, probably safer to use the jQuery global and $ as an alias within your function.

Comment: Thanks. I have implemented also with this. Any tip is appreciate

Comment: So you still have the same errors, even after instantiating the jquery framework before your addScript? This injects the necessary <script> calls for the jquery libraries before your <script>, so the jQuery errors should be subdued.

Comment: No no it works!!! Thanks ! ;)